# Один код выполняется по-разному

Tags: c++, c

Почему это

```
int x = nxt(), y = nxt();
arr[x] += y;
```

и это

```
arr[nxt()] += nxt();
```

выполняется по-разному?

Или

```
int x = nxt(), y = nxt(), z = nxt();
color((float)x / 255.0f, (float)y / 255.0f, (float)z / 255.0f);
```

и

```
color((float)nxt() / 255.0f, (float)nxt() / 255.0f, (float)nxt() / 255.0f);
```

В методе закраски цвета менялись местами красный и синий.

Очень сильно путает перестановка значений.

Comment: Стандарт не оговаривает последовательность вызовов в таких выражениях, как ваше. Не пишите такой код, который может быть трактован по-разному...

Comment: @Harry, понял, спасибо.

Comment: А массив `arr[]` у вас проинициализирован одинаково в обеих примерах?

Comment: @avp, да, одинаково